# Populate all months for multiIndex dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have a table with sales and forecast per month for thousands of products through 2015 - 2017.
My data gives the Demand & Forecast per each Site, Type, Product and Date (only months)

The issue is that if there is no sales & no forecast in a month I don't see the specific line. In the example below you see that the line for "2015-08-31" is missing.
I would like to see for this line a demand of 0 and a forecast of 0.
(See below an example with df_expected).

Basically I would like to fill this table with 0 for all dates between 2015-06-30 to 2017-09-30 for all Product/Type/Site combinations.

As you can see in the code I've not defined any index, but basically ["Site","Type","Product","Date"] could be seen as the multiIndex.

Note that I have millions of lines.

```
    import pandas as pd
data = [("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-31"),8,4),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-09-30"),2,4),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-10-31"),2,4),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-11-30"),4,4),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-31"),5,0),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-08-31"),1,3),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-10-31"),1,3),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-11-30"),3,3)]
labels = ["Site","Type","Product","Date","Demand","Forecast"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=labels)
df

   Site Type  Product       Date  Demand  Forecast
0   W1   G1     1234 2015-07-31       8         4
1   W1   G1     1234 2015-09-30       2         4
2   W1   G1     1234 2015-10-31       2         4
3   W1   G1     1234 2015-11-30       4         4
4   W1   G2     2345 2015-07-31       5         0
5   W1   G2     2345 2015-08-31       1         3
6   W1   G2     2345 2015-10-31       1         3
7   W1   G2     2345 2015-11-30       3         3
```

This is the result I am expecting

```
data_expected = [("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-31"),8,4),
                 ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-08-31"),0,0),
                 ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-09-30"),2,4),        
                 ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-10-31"),2,4),
                 ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-11-30"),4,4)]
df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected,columns=labels)
df_expected

  Site Type  Product        Date  Demand  Forecast
0   W1   G1     1234  2015-07-31       8         4
1   W1   G1     1234  2015-08-31       0         0
2   W1   G1     1234  2015-09-30       2         4
3   W1   G1     1234  2015-10-31       2         4
4   W1   G1     1234  2015-11-30       4         4
```

I was originally thinking about stack/unstack to make sure that I have all the months. But this is not optimal for a dataframe with millions of lines.

```
df = (df
      .set_index("Date")
      .groupby(["Site","Product","Type",pd.TimeGrouper('M')])[["Forecast","Demand"]].sum()
      .unstack()
      .fillna(0)
      .astype(int))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) with [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('Date')
       .groupby(["Site","Type","Product"])['Demand','Forecast']
       .resample('M')
       .asfreq()
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  Site Type  Product       Date  Demand  Forecast
0   W1   G1     1234 2015-07-31       8         4
1   W1   G1     1234 2015-08-31       0         0
2   W1   G1     1234 2015-09-30       2         4
3   W1   G1     1234 2015-10-31       2         4
4   W1   G1     1234 2015-11-30       4         4
```

EDIT:

I try a bit improve original solution with `fill_value` parameter in [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
(df.set_index("Date") 
   .groupby(["Site","Product","Type",pd.TimeGrouper('M')])['Dem‌​and','Forecast'].sum‌​() 
   .unstack(fill_value=0) 
   .stack())
```

Comment: It seems that my solution with stack/unstack is faster. With your technique it works for df with 10,000 lines. But if you run that on 1 million lines it takes a looooong time (i've never saw the solution actually)

Comment: Now I understand. I can only improve your solution - `(df.set_index("Date")
        .groupby(["Site","Product","Type",pd.TimeGrouper('M')])['Demand','Forecast'].sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack())` - Is it faster with your real data? If yes, I can add it to my answer.

Comment: I add it to answer ;)

Comment: I just keep astype for myself but it is not slowing doing the process.

Comment: Thank you. I try a lot for find better solution, but unstack/stack is very good. So only a bit improve it. Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The stack/unstack approach seems to work much faster.
with this all items have the same starting date and end date

```
df = (df.set_index("Date")
        .groupby(["Site","Product","Type",pd.TimeGrouper('M')])['Demand','Forecast'].sum()
        .unstack()
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .stack())


                              Demand  Forecast
Site Product Type Date                        
W1   1234    G1   2015-07-31       8         4
                  2015-08-31       0         0
                  2015-09-30       2         4
                  2015-10-31       2         4
                  2015-11-30       4         4
     2345    G2   2015-07-31       5         0
                  2015-08-31       1         3
                  2015-09-30       0         0
                  2015-10-31       1         3
                  2015-11-30       3         3
```

Comment: Can you output of your solution with test data? For me it return same dataframe as original. Maybe problem with pandas version, I use pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: So I understand you issue. The issue here is that if you populate only 4 lines of data this specific solution won't work as it does not populate any extra months. But if you run that on 1m lines then it gets all the right months. I will change initial data to reflect this.